# Mysql Database cannot start in XAMPP for Mac

Tags: mysql, xampp

Mysql Database suddenly cannot be start in my Mac. I already tried to run `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start` but it show the error `../Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (9346) - No such process
 ERROR!`. is there anyone know how to solve it please?. I already tried to `sudo killall mysqld` but still can't start.

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: just restart and try `sudo killall mysqld` then start again

Answer (score 3):

Open Xampp panel, in Mysql databse press configure and change the port from 3306 ->3310 for example and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue setting up xampp on MacOS 10.14.X... you can simply run `sudo killall mysqld` then `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

For some reason if the above command doesn't work for you!

Try this:

For XAMPP 7.3.31-2, I changed the port number from 3306 to 3307.

1. Click on Manage Servers
2. Select MySQL Database
3. Click on Configure on your right
4. Change your port number to 3307
5. Click OK
6. Close your Control Panel and relaunch it.

You are now good to go.